# Designing a mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model like this :

```
roomURL:String,
roomName: String,
owner:String,
dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
```

I need to store a list of all users accessing that a specific room ( roomURL). So , each time a user access this url i need to store his username so that i can get a list of all boards that a user has access. What is the best way to do this preferably using mongoose? Do i need to have another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally yes, created a new schema and have a collection as follows.

```
roomURL:String,
user:String
count:Number
```

and insert into this whenever someone tried to access a particular room.
Add that collection, but check if the combination of user and roomURL exists, if yes just increment the count.